# Are these two different ```RLIKE ^[^aeiou]``` and ```NOT RLIKE ^[aeiou]```?

Tags: mysql, sql

How is `NOT RLIKE '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'` different from `RLIKE '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'` ?

I was attempting mysql practice set on hackerrank and I cam across this doubt. At first I had a question to select all the cities from the table station that do not start **or** end with vowels. The query that gave me the answer was 
`SELECT city FROM station WHERE CITY NOT RLIKE '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$'`

The next question was to select all the cities from the table that do not start **and** do not end with a vowel. The previous line of code didn't give me the answer..
`SELECT city FROM station WHERE CITY RLIKE '^[^aeiou].*[^aeiou]$'`
gave me the right answer.

P.S: **station** is a table with columns id, city(this is the city name),state,long,lat.

Comment: Except of that both expressions won't work for single-character-strings - Which city name cause a problem with the second query?

Comment: I am not sure which city was causing a problem because it was a large dataset. But the problem was that the first one worked when it was an OR case i.e, not start or not end.. but wasn't working for the AND case

Answer (score 0):

They are not really similar at all.  Just by glancing at them, the first cares about the first and last characters.  The second does not.

So here is an example where they are different:

```
select col NOT RLIKE '^[aeiou].*[aeiou]$', col RLIKE '^[^aeiou].*'
from (select 'axyz' as col) x
```

Comment: the first cares about the first and last characters while the second does not? I am learning sql so i couldn't understand the query you've written entirely..

Comment: @SomeshwarRoychowdhury . . . This is not about SQL it is about regular expressions.